# Getting null value for object bind with @ModelAttribute

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Using - Spring Boot, Thymeleaf

I have following code under controller class:

```
public class HotelController {
    
    private HotelService hotelService;
    private HotelRepository hotelRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    public HotelController(HotelService hotelService,HotelRepository hotelRepository) {
        this.hotelService = hotelService;
        this.hotelRepository = hotelRepository;
    }
    


    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String searchHotel(Model model) {
        Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
        model.addAttribute("searchObject",hotel);
        model.addAttribute("cityList", hotelRepository.findListOfCities());
        model.addAttribute("hotelList", hotelRepository.findListOfHotels());
        return "search_hotel";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/availabilityResult")
    public String afterClickingSearch(@ModelAttribute("searchObject") Hotel hotel,Model model) {
        if(hotelService.searchHotelResult(hotel)==null) 
            return "failure_page";
        else {
            model.addAttribute("hotelRoom_TypePriceGST",hotelService.findHotelPriceandRoomType(hotel.getCity(),hotel.getHotel()).split(","));
            model.addAttribute("total", hotelService.findTotal(hotel.getCity(), hotel.getHotel()));
            return "booking_confirmation";
        }
            
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/navUserRegisterPage")
    public String userRegisterPage(Model model){
        User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute("userObj", user);
        return "user_registerForm";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/reserveUser")
    public String reserveUserHandler(@ModelAttribute("userObj") User user,@ModelAttribute("searchObject") Hotel hotel,Model model) {
        System.out.println(hotel.getHotel());
        System.out.println(user.getGuest_name());
        model.addAttribute("hotelName", hotel.getHotel());
        model.addAttribute("userName", user.getGuest_name());
        return "confirmation_page";
    }
}
```

I can find hotel value(usig hotel.getHotel()) under handler method-  public String afterClickingSearch()

But when I try to find the hotel value(using hotel.getHotel()) under handler method -reserveUserHandler(); I get null as value.

Please help with how can I retrieve hotel value under reserveUserHandler() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though you have a Hotel backed form on the "search_hotel" page and the action goes to `afterClickingSearch()`. You can access the Hotel model attribute in `afterClickingSearch()` because you are submitting the attributes of the Hotel in your form. When you transition to "booking_confirmation" and other pages it's not apparent that you are passing the hotel's id to maintain state.

You have a few options, some more elegant than others. You can pass around the hotel's id via a request parameter. A second option is to include a hidden Hotel id in all forms from which `reserveUserHandler()` is reachable, making sure each form is initialized with the id, and lookup the hotel by id in `reserveUserHandler()`. A third option, which I wouldn't recommend, is to make Hotel or Hotel id a session attribute. See [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-session-attributes) for more information on session attributes. When you use session attributes you need to be wary of multiple browser tabs and how unique state is maintained across each tab.